# Setting up cookies in ASP.NET Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I'm using ASP.NET Membership everywhere in the site like logging, creating account etc. How do I set up for it to use a cookie. For instance, once the user logs in keep the user logged in for like 2 hours using cookies. Right now it seems it is not using cookies. Do I set something in the web.config of the webpage. How do I also specify how long until the cookie expires? Is cookies supported/integrated in asp.net membership by the way?

Comment: Are you trying to do a "Remember Me" type thing? if so I'm pretty sure that is supported in ASP.NET Authentication class

Comment: Yes. How do I combine this with forms authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Forms Authentication? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie(v=vs.90).aspx

Whatever auth provider you use is responsible for setting the cookie (if any) and determining when the login session expires.

For asp.net Forms authentication in your web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: I'm using Sql server membership for validating user and forms authentication.

Comment: How does the Membership and FormsAuthentication work? Do I authenticate using Membership first and the FormsAuthentication? Do I have to check Membership.GetUser() everytime to find out that the user is logged in?

Comment: What version of asp.net and/or MVC are you using?

Comment: I got it working. Do Membership first and then FormsAuthentication and do authentication.Redirectopage(x, ispersistlogin) and always check against formsauthentication to check whether the user is logged in. Thanks.

Comment: Nope. Classic asp.net 4.5. Not MVC.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the standard asp.net login controls then set the `DisplayRememberMe` property to true:

```
<asp:Login DisplayRememberMe="True|False" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.displayrememberme(v=vs.100).aspx

If you are using a custom login page then you after authenticating the user I think you can just call

```
SetAuthCookie(
    string userName,
    bool createPersistentCookie)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b(v=vs.90).aspx

To set the timeout you can use the web.config file:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="525600" />
 </authentication>
```